# Change EE native multi edit?

Tags: ee2

Just wondering if it's possible to change what fields appear on the multi edit screen. Currently the editable fields in multi edit are, Title, Url title, Status, Entry date, Make entry sticky, & Allow comment.

My end goal is to allow fields from the Store module in the multi edit screen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I think the closest you'll get is using the [Henshu](http://zenbustudio.com/software/henshu) add-on, from Zenbu Studio. It's basically designed to implement bulk/inline editing in the edit entries list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave Henshu a try, unfortunately it's multi edit is the same as native EE. And store has yet to give support for Zenbu & Henshu.

Comment: Henshu 1.0 was released with **multi-entry custom field editing**: http://zenbustudio.com/software/docs/henshu#multi_entry_editing Keep in mind this is a "change selected entries's custom field data all to X" kind of feature. As for Zenbu, Store still needs to add compatibility to display their data. The tools have been available for a while and can be found here: http://zenbustudio.com/software/dev/zenbu

Answer (score 2):

The [Bulk Edit add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bulk-edit) can do this for you, I've used it successfully in the past.